# проверить поступление новых данных в таблицу используя Python

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица в базе данных(postgresql) она пополняется хаотично несколько раз в день,
есть уникальное значение в виде timestamp.
Как наилучшим способом определить, что в таблице появились новые данные и если это так, то дать сигнал для загрузки только **новых** данных в другую таблицу.
Пока, что планирую сделать несколько функций в даге и между ними сенсор
но никак не могу сообразить, как "поймать" свежую порцию.
Есть вариант где-то хранить данные с последним временем загрузки, но хотелось бы обойтись без лишних таблиц.

Comment: сделать таблицу, в которую будут добавляться id новых и обновленных записей, сделать триггеры, на той таблице где хранятся данные, которые будут добавлять id в эту таблицу когда записи в основной и таблице обновляются. Периодически проверять таблицу с id на наличие записей и забирать записи с id из этой таблицы из основной таблицы, после успешного получения данных  очищать таблицу с id

Comment: моя версия бд по-моему не поддерживает create trigger или вы имели ввиду обычный sql запрос?

Comment: Ну либо хранить где-то отдельно последний уже загруженный `timestamp`, загружать всё, что после этого `timestamp` и обновлять его. Либо сделать в таблице какое-то поле, например `loaded`, дефолтное значение `0`, а после считывания данных с `loaded = 0` в другую таблицу выставлять считанным `1` там. Каждый метод имеет свои плюсы и минусы. Первый по идее экономнее, зато второй позволяет обновить не только новые данные, но, при необходимости, и старым данным сбросить этот признак и обновить их.

Comment: @CrazyElf, какие недостатки у этого варианта? insert into table_2 (столбец_0, ... , столбец_n) (select столбец_0, ... , столбец_n from table_1 where "timestamp" > (select "timestamp" from table_2 order by "timestamp" DESC limit 1)

Comment: А, ну, кстати, да, я забыл, что можно просто из второй таблицы взять )

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать уведомления
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-notify

Comment: интересно, возможно я даже и где-то применю это, но не совсем то, что мне нужно, я думаю над select - как сравнивание таблицы А с таблицей В, если в таблице А есть что-то большее чем в В - загрузить в В.... как-то так

Comment: тогда первое что приходит:

insert into table_2 (столбец_0, ... , столбец_n)
(select столбец_0, ... , столбец_n
 from table_1
 where 
  "timestamp" > (select "timestamp" from table_2 order by "timestamp" DESC limit 1)
 )

Comment: @Ghostik2005, главное не забыть добавить `on conflict (<some key>) do update` иначе будем получать ошибки

Comment: @Ghostik2005, а что значит DESC limit 1? это же не ограничение количества?